# Unmarshalling BPEL document using JAXB

Tags: java, jaxb, bpel

I am using JAXB to unmarshal BPEL document(generated by eclipse BPEL plug in) using BPEL schema `xmlns:bpel="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsbpel/2.0/process/executable"`. The problem is that literal values are not unmarshalled correctly. If I try to access the below BPEL code using the following code, i get "null" result. Whereas "TFrom" and "TCopy "are jaxb generated classes.

```
List<TExtensibleElements> copy = exp.copyOrExtensionAssignOperation;
for(TExtensibleElements tex: copy){
if(tex instanceof TCopy){

TFrom from = ((TCopy) tex).getFrom();

if(from.getVariable() == null){ 
    List<Object> fromContent = from.getContent();
    for(Object obj: fromContent){
    if(obj instanceof TLiteral)
        System.out.println("from literal:"+ ((TLiteral)obj).toString() );

    }

}       
----------------------------------------------------------
<bpel:assign validate="no" name="AssignApproved">                                       
<bpel:copy>
   <bpel:from>
    <bpel:literal>
       <tns:BankLoanProcessResponse xmlns:tns="http://bankloanprocess"               xmlns:xsi=   "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <tns:result>Approved</tns:result>

         </tns:BankLoanProcessResponse>
       </bpel:literal>
     </bpel:from>
    <bpel:to variable="output" part="payload"></bpel:to>
  </bpel:copy>

 </bpel:assign>
```

Thanks,
monika

Comment: Can you post the generated code of TLiteral here (or as a gist)?

Comment: //@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    //@XmlType(name = "tLiteral", propOrder = {
    //"content"
    //})
    public class TLiteral {

    //@XmlMixed
    //@XmlAnyElement(lax = true)
    protected List<Object> content;

      public List<Object> getContent() {
        if (content == null) {
            content = new ArrayList<Object>();
        }
        return this.content;
    }

  
    

    }